# Convert JSON to parameters - GET / POST request

Tags: json, parameters

I'm trying to convert JSON to normal parameters so i can send the info with GET requset, however i'm not able to.

Tried encoding, different methods nothing worked for me so far.

JSON:

`{"data":{"company_name":"infosec","addressType":"shipping","firstname":"infosec","lastname":"infosec","street":"infosec 1337","phone":"123456789","city":"infosec","cid":"","tin":"","zip":"1337","email":""}`

I want to be able to send it via GET request or POST with normal parameters.

Comment: to send data to server you should be using a post request... just create a POST request with content-type: application/json and add your json to the body and post it.

Comment: Yea, but i want to send it also in parameters not sure why it doesnt work.

Comment: to send in `params` your need update in the route, else you can pass the attr and values as `query params`  as `http://example.com/path/to/page?name=ferret&color=purple`

Comment: are you talking about data atribute? i think thats why its not letting me to send it in params, when the data its not there its working fine.

Comment: cool... please mark my answer if it was helpfull to you

Comment: please answer my question

Comment: can you please explain data attr ?

Comment: I have to send it with it, otherwise respone is 404. check the json i posted please.
My question is how would i send whole json in parameters.